# Анализ временных рядов

Tags: статистика, анализ

Доброго времени суток.

У меня довольно странная задача. Но что есть, то есть. 
Есть человек(испытуемый), к нему крепится на каждую руку по 5 датчиков. и есть аппаратура которая отслеживает координаты этих датчиков в каждый момент времени. Сначала человек 3 минуты совершает одинаковые движения рукой от себя и к себе. 
Снимаются показания. Дальше человек только представляет что двигает рукой. Также снимаются показания.
Итого, есть 2 файла, в каждом из которых по 30 столбиков(10 датчиков * 3 координаты). Первый файл - это положение датчиков в течении 3х минут движения. Второй - это положение датчиков при представлении движения.

Вообще изначально от меня требовалось по второму файлу говорить были ли реальные движения. Но потом решили более скромную задачу поставить. Попытаться хотя бы найти закономерности какие-либо между двумя файлами. Пока что я строил графики, считал коэффициенты корреляции между столбиками.

Хотелось бы получить от людей, которые занимаются анализом рядов, какие-нибудь советы, что еще можно сделать с такими наборами данных.. Какие можно эксперименты провести. И т.д.